# How Apache Flink manages MQTT consumer offsets

Tags: apache-flink, mqtt

I'm using MQTT consumer as my flink job's data source. I'm wondering how to save the data offsets into checkpoint to ensure that no data lost when flink cluster restarts after a failure. I've see lots of articles introducing how apache flink manages kafka consumer offsets. Does anyone know whether apache flink has its own function to manage MQTT consumer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul read [state-backends](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/state/state_backends/#state-backends) part of documentation. And [checkpoints](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/state/checkpoints/#checkpoints) section.

> When checkpointing is enabled, managed state is persisted to ensure
> consistent recovery in case of failures. Where the state is persisted
> during checkpointing depends on the chosen Checkpoint Storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MQTT consumer, you should make sure it uses the Data Source API. You can read about that on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/sources/  - That also includes how to work integrate with checkpointing. You can also read the details in FLIP-27 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface